# Create union type from array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects:

```
const arr = [{
  value: 'value1',
  key: 'key1'
}, {
  value: 'value2',
  key: 'key2'
}]
```

What I want to achieve is to get an union type having the values of `value` key.

```
type Values = 'value1' | 'value2';
```

How can I define the type to generate it automatically from the array of objects?

Comment: You need to do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxjVGw) or the equivalent.